# File upload doesn't happens successfully on Firefox 3.6 whereas it is successful on Firefox 2.0

Tags: html, character-encoding, multipartform-data

I'm facing some problem with file upload feature on my application on Firefox 3.6. The file upload feature is successful on firefox 2.0, but recently our customer upgraded to firefox 3.6 and the feature stopped working.

I visited many forms but could not find the actual reason for this problem. The code for "multipart/form-data" is that we are using CONTENT TYPE header and enctype as multipart/form-data.

CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\
enctype="multipart/form-data"

Does utf-8 and "multipart/form-data" combination has some problem with Firefox 3.6 version???

Also the Tomcat version used is 5.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 3.x is terribly out of date.
Mozilla does not support it anymore.
So if you have problems on firefox 3.x , you should at least upgrade to 4.x.
Have you tried your app feature on other generations of FF?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes , but our customer is using it, and I fear that they won't upgrade it immediately !

Comment: Okay, digging deeper, I would like to know what do you mean by, 'feature stopped working', what exactly is happening when you try to use it?

Comment: Nothing happens, I mean page does not get refreshed at all !! Ideally it should show a message that "File Uploaded successfully". The action never completes !!

Comment: Also I found a related post here on this website !! But could not figure out what could be the solution .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522620/html-forms-issues-combining-charset-with-enctype-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: You would like to visit this http://cutesoft.net/forums/thread/67234.aspx people had the same issue and some got their fix. Just go through the page you will find the solution in the bottom.

Comment: I visited the forum and tried the same, but the problem does not look same to me !! (((((( and it does not solve problem too !

Comment: The problem finally got resolved as there was a bug at web server side. The firefox changed the way multipart requests are processed (changing some http header syntax ) which was causing web server to fail. We have our own internal web server, so web server team fixed the issue for us. However, I dont have much details what and how exactly they fixed the problem !